# How to improve performance for read only innodb MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, concurrency

I have a particular task which is to maximize the concurrent performance. There is only one particular type of query, which is

```
select * from table where col1 between ? and ? and col2 between ? and ?
```

I have created a composite index for (col1, col2). The table is about 20G in size and 100 million rows

However, even in peak concurrent requests, the CPU utilization for MySQL is only 30%. I have tried various techniques like increase `max_connections`, `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` but none of them are working.

How to maximize the configuration so that it can perform such read-only query to extreme?

Comment: increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` be the thing to change to have an effect. What is its current value? `max_connections` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` are unlikely to improve. Look at `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "innodb_buffer_pool_%"` look at [innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests) vs `innodb_buffer_pool_reads` when you before/and after re-reruning the query. How many rows does the `col1` range correspond to? I assume its less than the `col2` range?

Comment: I have changed `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of memory but still the same 30% CPU. About 20000 rows correspond to `col1` range

Comment: Please post TEXT of A) your query, B) text results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * (rest of your query); C) text results of SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name; D) text results of SHOW INDEX FROM table_name;  E) do you REALLY need all the columns in the result?

Comment: @Barry Please post complete MySQLTuner report after 24 hours uptime for us to have a sense of your instance workload, since you have not posted any other information requested.

Answer (score 1):

Can't optimize it without some serious surgery.  Think of it as a "bounding box" as discussed in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

It discusses 5 ways of doing "find nearest".  You are on the second-worst, and probably do not have the best indexes for that.  Then it moves on to 3 faster ways to run the query, but they require non-trivial effort.  But the speedup is quite significant.

As for concurrency, those algorithms provide performance by decreasing the I/O *and* CPU.  This allows for more concurrency and even lower CPU usage.